# google flights, search without amound of days, trip lenth

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

in the older version of google flight, when looking at the calendar, it would show the lowest price, no matter the trip length

but now we are forced to choose amount of days and it only searches according to amount of days for trip at one time.

is there a way to go back to searching the on all trip lengths ?

maybe finding the cheapest one-way, and then finding the return can be useful, but sometimes one-way prices arent proportional

i tried sky scanner, but then not all the dates show prices, and i couldnt fix that, i had to check the missing date one by one..

Comment: ITA Matrix allows you to input a variable length of stay - something like 5-9 for the number of days.

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming your origin is fixed. In that case you can still do the 'Explore Destinations' on Google flights. Alternatively you can also go to skiplagged.com, go to the center of the home page, enter your origin and click on Search Deals. Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Flightbot (https://flightbot.com) has something kind of like this where at the very least, you can search for the cheapest prices across a range of trip lengths (e.g., 4-10 days). For example, take a look at this trip for the lowest prices from San Francisco to Hong Kong:

https://flightbot.com/search/SFO/HKGA/Economy/period/4-10-days?dateFilterType=none

[image: Loweest prices across a range of dates]